# Display formatted string from array in DataGridView DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

Is there a way to display a formatted string from an array attribute while the list is bounded to the DataGridView?

I am currently using the following code:

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<Stage>(stageList);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
dv.DataSource = source;
dv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;


internal class Stage
{
     .
     public bool isNew {get; protected internal set; }
     public int Id { get; protected internal set; }
     public short[] Level { get; protected internal set; } = new short[4];
     .
     .
}
```

Both the "isNew" and "Id" attributes appear properly.
I was hoping to get the following sample output:

```
IsNew   |   Id  |   Stage
 [✓]        1       1/5/7/9
 [ ]        2       2/3/8/9
 [ ]        3       3/5/8/10
```

where Stage is an array with 4 elements formatted as

```
string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", Stage[0], Stage[1], Stage[2], Stage[3]);
```

Comment: You could use CellFormatting or expose a read only property which returns the formatted data

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private void dv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Stage")
    {
        formatting.Value = //your code to format data for this column;
    }
}
```